# abs function in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I wrote some code in C (not in C++):

```
Mask1 = abs(Area1 * 2 + Area2 * -2);
```

Area1, Area2 and Mask1 are three double variables. (e.g. 3.00556, 34.3333) 
My problem is that abs returns an integer value (e.g 30).

What I need to do to fix it?

Regards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `fabs`

Comment: Note that this is because C doesn't support method overloading, for those coming from "other" languages.

Comment: In fact, C doesn't even have methods.  It only has functions. ;)

Answer (score 5):

fabs
http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fabs/

Answer (score 5):

`abs()` takes an integer as an argument and returns an integer result.  Your doubles are being automatically truncated to integers.  A decent C++ compiler would give you a warning. ;)

The function to use here is `fabs()` for doubles or `fabsf()` for floats.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fabs()`

Answer (score 0):

use fabs()